# How to make Rails 'forget' that I used migration rollback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I rolled back a couple of steps, everything went fine but now I cannot just use rake db:migration command to run my new migrations, it runs all those reverted migrations again instead of the most recent one, so I have to run the latest migration by its specific version which is not convenient at all. How can I fix it?

Comment: if some migrations are now useless, remove them

Comment: why not just delete them...?

Comment: if you don't want older migration you may comment or remove,if you can't remove them then create migration which will do reverse like remove table or alter column ,remove column that kind of migration so if previous migration runs it will remove older migration effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just comment code in migrations or delete them if they are no longer needed

Answer (score 0):

There should be a table called 'schema_migrations' in your database. Rails adds an entry to this table for each migration it no longer needs to run. Similarly, Rails removes the relevant entry from this table when reverting a migration.

You could just manually add the entries for the migrations you don't wish to run anymore.